# YouTube Android Player API - ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, android, youtube, screen-orientation, android-youtube-api

Note: I'm using the [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

**Expected behavior:**

- The activity remains in portrait mode when the video is not fullscreen (Enforced by `AndroidManifest` ok).
- The activity is set to landscape orientation when the video enters fullscreen mode (ok).
- The activity returns to portrait orientation when the user exits fullscreen mode (`ExceptionInInitializerError` occurs here).

[See the problem in action here](https://imgur.com/a/pP2tR)

[YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity.java](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/658fa4a62e5497c1595119dd22d9007c) (This is included in the library under `sample/src/com/examples/youtubeapidemo`)

**Main Activity**

```
package test.testapp;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;

public class MainActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener {

    static final String API_KEY = "PLACE YOUTUBE DATA API KEY HERE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
        youTubeView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
        youTubePlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(this);
        youTubePlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI);
        if(!wasRestored){
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo("wKJ9KzGQq0w");
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen) {
        if(isFullscreen){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }else if(!isFullscreen){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="test.testapp.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Stack trace**

```
06-10 09:47:09.205 2646-2646/test.testapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onSaveInstanceState(SourceFile:201)
        at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:11839)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:2576)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchSaveInstanceState(SourceFile:220)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2562)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2562)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2562)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2562)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2562)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2562)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2562)
        at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:11822)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1566)
        at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1188)
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity.onSaveInstanceState(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1137)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3486)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rt
        at rs.<clinit>(SourceFile:17)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onSaveInstanceState(SourceFile:201) 
        at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:11839) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchFreezeSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:2576) 
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchSaveInstanceState(SourceFile:220) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2562) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2562) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2562) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2562) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2562) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2562) 
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2562) 
        at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:11822) 
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.saveHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1566) 
        at android.app.Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1188) 
        at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity.onSaveInstanceState(Unknown Source) 
        at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1137) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1215) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3486) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the application is crashing when restarting because of a configuration change

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

You can disable the automatic activity recreation for orientation changes, and handle it yourself.

To do that, add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|screenSize"
```

With orientation alone it probably works, but the other ones I think were triggered also on some devices.

You can then override onConfigurationChanged() to do stuff on an orientation change if you need it, like showing / hiding views, etc.. as Android will **not** recreate your layouts automatically (that's what it does when restarts the activity on an orientation change)

So you can do:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfiguration) {

      Log.wtf(
        "Orientation", 
        newConfiguration.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT 
             ? "portrait"
             : "landscape"
      );

}
```

Comment: Besides that, you are masking the fact that Youtube Player will probably crash if tried to be restarted. That will probably happen when your app is in the background, destroyed by android, then reopened...

Comment: in my experience yt player crashes quite a lot so I ended up using it as a Fragment then destroying it manually on every onStop.