# YouTube API Exception In Initializer Error

Tags: android, youtube-api

So I have been using the YouTube API successfully for the past few months in Android Studio. I went to update my app and as of today the app keeps crashing when it is trying to initialize the YouTube builder. Has anyone else experienced this problem?

```
mYoutubeDataApi = new YouTube.Builder(mTransport, mJsonFactory, null)
                                .setApplicationName(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                                .build();
```

The app crashes with the following output:

```
2019-12-09 01:38:06.443 17937-17937/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube.<clinit>(YouTube.java:44)
        at com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube$Builder.build(YouTube.java:16644)
```

Line 44 in the YouTube.java file is:

```
public class YouTube extends com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient {

  // Note: Leave this static initializer at the top of the file.
  static {
    com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkState(
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.MAJOR_VERSION == 1 &&
        com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.MINOR_VERSION >= 15,
        "You are currently running with version %s of google-api-client. " +
        "You need at least version 1.15 of google-api-client to run version " +
        "1.30.1 of the YouTube Data API library.", com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.VERSION);
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YouTube Android Player API - ExceptionInInitializerError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472018/youtube-android-player-api-exceptionininitializererror)

Answer (score 3):

In 1.30.6, they added this: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/pull/1419

To fix, edit your build.gradle back down to 1.30.5

```
dependencies {
  implementation ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.30.5')
  implementation ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.30.5')
}
```

If there's a better solution, I'd like to hear it!

---

To further explain why that change in 1.30.6 causes the crash, here's some more info.

Specifically, the issue is coming from this file: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/master/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleUtils.java

```
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.ensureMatch(Matcher.java:1116)
        at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:382)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleUtils.<clinit>(Unknown Source:26)
```

Here is the relevant code

```
  public static final String VERSION = getVersion();

  static final Pattern VERSION_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)(-SNAPSHOT)?");

  static {
    Matcher versionMatcher = VERSION_PATTERN.matcher(VERSION);
    versionMatcher.find();
    MAJOR_VERSION = Integer.parseInt(versionMatcher.group(1));
    MINOR_VERSION = Integer.parseInt(versionMatcher.group(2));
    BUGFIX_VERSION = Integer.parseInt(versionMatcher.group(3));
  }

private static String getVersion() {
    String version = GoogleUtils.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
    // in a non-packaged environment (local), there's no implementation version to read
    if (version == null) {
      // fall back to reading from a properties file - note this value is expected to be cached
      try (InputStream inputStream =
          GoogleUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("google-api-client.properties")) {
        if (inputStream != null) {
          Properties properties = new Properties();
          properties.load(inputStream);
          version = properties.getProperty("google-api-client.version");
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // ignore
      }
    }
    return version;
  }
```

Presumably, getVersion is returning null, although I can't say why. Seeing as how this recently happened for me 2-3 days ago also, something we updated must be conflicting.

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, it was baffling me too. Hopefully there's a better solution than downgrading as now we're stuck on this version essentially. But for the meantime... Guess it works. I think you have to mark my answer as 'accepted'

Comment: Thanks - just wasted 2 hours on this stupid issue before finally coming across this. Bug reported here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/issues/1451

Answer (score 1):

This bug is fixed in com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.30.7. Upgrading to that version or later will fix it.

Comment: Nope, this still happens in 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.31.4'

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version, they have added the library [proguard](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/main/google-api-client/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/google-api-client.pro) file, which keeps the the [GoogleUtils.java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/main/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleUtils.java) and hence keeps the `google-api-client.properties` which gets generated in build time.

Initially they used to update the string literal for version name for each release hence that time parsing of version name done in [GoogleUtils.java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/e921d949e2b2cf7941c4d8b2de5b44012b81c93b/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleUtils.java) was crash free.

But later on they shifted to parsing the version from `google-api-client.properties` at [GoogleUtils.java](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/blob/a6c6decbd4a162ff4030e2c3f74c72eb6ac9eddb/google-api-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleUtils.java) which started giving error as proguard started removing the generated `google-api-client.properties` file.

Later on after release, [1.30.9](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/compare/v1.30.8...v1.30.9) at this [commit id](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/commit/8a59ed071f19d9b78d284cdc75181ee102ca9c61) the started using the embedded proguard rule to keep the *GoogleUtils.java* file

They actually fixed the issue at release, [1.30.8](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/compare/v1.30.7...v1.30.8) at the [commit](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/commit/b70e8ef1145fad30bfe02e91d4dc9e278fd2d519), `1.30.9` release just does the same fix in more android recommended way.

Although the final adopted version uses `GoogleUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("google-api-client.properties")` which is Java api and returns the `InputStream` to read the `google-api-client.properties` file. Since these stream may not work perfectly in some devices they still crash but with lesser frequency(as we still see the crashes with the fixed present in the release `1.30.9`).

Created an [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/issues/2159) to track this